# Компаратор для сортировки в классе

Tags: c++, классы, сортировка, compare

Имею такие методы:

```
const bool Date::compare_dates(const Date &d1, const Date &d2) const {
    return d1 < d2;
}

void Date::sort_dates(Date *dates, const int &num) const {
    std::sort(dates[0], dates[num - 1], compare_dates);
}
```

В месте вызова **compare_dates** возникает еррор:

```
Reference to non-static member function must be called
```

Как это понимать?

Comment: `dates[0]` и `dates[num - 1]` — это ссылки на даты, а не указатели, а должно быть `dates` и `dates + num`, ня?

Answer (score 3):

### Сделайте метод сравнения статическим (в заголовочном файле):

```
class Date
{
//...
    static bool compare_dates(const Date &d1, const Date &d2) const;
//...
};
```

Вызов:

```
void Date::sort_dates(Date *dates, const int &num) const
{
    std::sort(dates[0], dates[num - 1], Date::compare_dates);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь компилируется! Но сортировка работает не так, как надо. Если изволите прочесть дальше, я буду благодарен.
Я поправил метод сортировки:

    void sort_dates(Date *dates, const int &num) {
        std::sort(dates, dates + num, Date::compare_dates);
    }

(ибо явно обозначая границы массива компиль ругается на несовпадение типов в пакете algorithm).
Но сортировка производится всегда по месяцам. Оператор < перегружен. Что не так?

Comment: Если метод сделан статическим, то никакой необходимости исправлять `compare_dates` на `Date::compare_dates` нет. Более того, если уже определен оператор сравнения `<` для класса `Date`, то зачем вообще понадобился этот `compare_dates`? Никакой необходимости в нем нет.

Answer (score 0):

ошибки:

1. Ваш компаратор метод класса и должен вызываться обьектом, поэтому он
   не может иметь два аргумента. Если вы не хотите сделать его
   статической функцией (не связанный с обьектом), то она должна
   получать один аргумент, поскольку первым аргументом будет *this, т.е. обьект, для которого вызывается метод.
2. Дальше вы в стандартном альгоритме хотите вызвать функцию без
   обьекта.  Чтобы исправить эту ошибку, нужно передать указатель на метод, функтору, который для каждого обьекта вызовит  метод.

Я пытался показать как нужно поступать вообше, а для   вашего случая компаратор и не нужен вовсе. Если он у вас сравнивает два обьекта этого же типа,то у вас определен оператор меньше, и стандартный альгоритм без компаратора именно так и сравнит.

Выходит вам нужно убрать Date::compare_dates и не передавать альгоритму компаратор:

```
void Date::sort_dates(Date *dates, const int &num) const
{
       std::sort(dates[0], dates[num - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Простите, здесь полно ужасов, но, раз Вы говорите, что компаратор не требуется, то касаемо реализации сортировки у меня возник отдельный вопрос. Могли бы, пожалуйста, помочь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be

Comment: А что вы называете ужасом?  Я ошибаюсь или плохо излогаю?

Comment: Во-первых, `std::mem_fun_ref` уже давно deprecated. Теперь - `std::mem_fn`. Во-вторых, вы пользуетесь ей неправильно. `std::mem_fun_ref` просто превращает метод в функциональный объект. Но она не "связывает" никаких параметров. Ваш объект по прежнему имеет *три* параметра и компаратором служить не может. После `std::mem_fn` надо еще делать `std::bind`.

Comment: @AnT, вы совершенно правы во всем. Это причина моей рассеянности. А 
 вот по поводу   std::mem_fun_ref уже давно deprecated..._  мое мнение: устарел, но еще остается в стандарте...И еще, впринципе и то и другое устарели. Уж лучше лямбда выражением пользоваться

Answer (score 0):

Это означает, что просто `compare_dates` является некорректным синтаксисом в С++. Имя метода класса может использоваться только в ограниченном наборе синтаксических контекстов, вроде вызова метода класса, взятия адреса метода класса и т.п. У вас же просто ни с того ни с сего в списке аргументов болтается одинокое `compare_dates`. Что это?

Отдельно непонятно, почему вы пытаетесь передавать `dates[0]` и `dates[num - 1]` в списке аргументов. Если ваша задача - отсортировать массив `dates`, то можно предположить, что передавать надо `dates` и `dates + num`... И почему у вас вдруг стало `num - 1`? И зачем вы сделали передачу `num` по ссылке?

Ну и самое главное, почему-то до сих пор не упомянутое в ответах: если у вас уже определен оператор сравнения `<` для класса `Date`, то зачем вам вообще понадобился этот метод `compare_dates`? Никакой необходимости в этом `compare_dates` нет. Просто пишите

```
std::sort(dates, dates + num);
```