# Сортировка массива класса работает неправильно

Tags: c++, классы, сортировка, дата

Заголовок: https://pastebin.com/AXU1K0Wm

Реализация класса: https://pastebin.com/AqU4BxPV

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "date_class.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Date d1(1907, 2, 13);
    Date d2(1907, 2, 12);
    Date d3(2015, 3, 18);
    Date d4(1998, 1, 17);

    Date dates[4]{d3, d4, d1, d2};

    for (const auto &date : dates)
        date.print_date();

    sort_dates(dates, 4);


    cout << endl;

    for (const auto &date : dates)
        date.print_date();

//    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
 2015/3/18
 1998/1/17
 1907/2/13
 1907/2/12 //исходный массив

 1998/1/17
 1907/2/12
 1907/2/13
 2015/3/18 //после сортировки
```

Что так, что qsort - результат тот же. Что не так?

Comment: Все зависит от того, определили ли вы  bool  Date::operator<(const Date&) ? И если определили, то как?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вы же открывали код?

Comment: Теперь увидел ссыльку и посмотрел. Но  вы определили оператор меньше неправильно же.  Альгоритм увидев, что  один из данных (год, месяц и день) не меньше, ничего не меняет местами. Естественно вы не получите желаемый результат. Пишите оператор< так, что, если годы  равны, то сравнивались  месяцы, если же годы больше, то сразу возвращать 0, и  та же логика с месяцами, а то у вас дни больше, а годы меньше, и  получаете ложь... Погуглите, посотрите как этот оператор пишут для  класса Даты

Comment: На будущее: Когда задаете вопрос, [приводите код сразу в тексте вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Не целиком, а в виде [минимального рабочего примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (Например, все эти примочки вроде `is_leap_year` к делу не относятся - их лучше убрать.) Этим вы сэкономите нам время (нам не придется переходить по ссылкам и пролистывать не относящийся к делу код) и увеличите свой шанс получить нормальный ответ и не отхватить минусов.

Answer (score 5):

Вот есть у вас две даты:

```
a = 1998/1/17
b = 1907/2/12
```

Как `std::sort` станет определять, какая из них должна идти перед какой?

Правильно, вызовом `operator<` (другие операторы сравнения он не использует). Смотрим на ваш код для этого оператора:

```
const bool Date::operator<(const Date &d2) const {
    return this->m_year <= d2.m_year && this->m_month <= d2.m_month && this->m_day < d2.m_day;
}
```

Если вы подставите сюда те две даты, то в обоих случаях (`a < b` и `b < a`) получите `false`.

Глупо получается. Даты разные, но ни одна из них не меньше другой.

Из-за этого для `std::sort` эти две даты равны (более правильно сказать, "эквивалентны") - он может расположить их относительно друг друга в произвольном порядке.

Реализация *правильного* `operator<` "в лоб" выглядит примерно так:

```
bool Date::operator<(const Date &d2) const
{
    int x;

    x = m_year - d2.m_year;
    if (x != 0) return x < 0;

    x = m_month - d2.m_month;
    if (x != 0) return x < 0;

    x = m_day - d2.m_day;
    if (x != 0) return x < 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Обратите внимание, я убрал `const` из возвращаемого типа. В этом случае он ничего не делает.

---

Есть и более продвинутый способ:

Добавляете к своему классу метод, который возвращает `std::tuple` из ссылок на все поля, как-то так:

```
auto tie() const
{
    return std::tie(m_year, m_month, m_day);
}
```

Тогда `operator<` можно записать просто как:

```
bool operator<(const Date &d2) const
{
    return tie() < d2.tie();
}
```

Аналогично пишутся остальные операторы: `>` `<=` `>=` `==` `!=`.

Answer (score 4):

Вы операторы сравнения не корректно реализовали. Например, если год меньше, месяц тоже, а день больше, то ваш оператор "меньше" вернет ложь:

```
const bool Date::operator < (const Date & d2) const
{
     return 2018 <= 2019 && 1 <= 12 && 10 < 20;  // 2018.1.10 < 2019.12.20
}
```

Правильная реализация:

```
const bool Date::operator<(const Date &d2) const 
{
    return  (m_year <  d2.m_year)
         || (m_year == d2.m_year && m_month <  d2.m_month) 
         || (m_year == d2.m_year && m_month == d2.m_month && m_day < d2.m_day);
}
```

Остальные операторы по аналогии.

Comment: Господи, и у меня ушло на это три часа... Ну что ж, спасибо, буду бдительнее :)

Comment: @xt1zer Вы я вижу новенький, тут не принято спасибы писать, комметарии для обсуждения по делу

Comment: @Cerbo Ну, [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) наоборот предлагают благодарить отвечающих. :)

Comment: А что это у вас за оператор сравнения такой реализован? Чем он лучше неправильного оператора автора вопроса? `m_year  < d2.m_year  || m_month < d2.m_month || ...` - это уже полная бессмыслица.

Comment: Минус такого подхода к реализации сравнения - нужно не O(n), а O(n^2) строчек (n - число полей). Да и ошибку заметить сложнее.

Comment: @AnT Ваша правда

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже сказали, ваш оператор сравнения реализует какую-то бессмыслицу.

В соответствии с современными веяниями в С++ (весьма разумными), лексикографическое (или вообще любое нетривиальное) сравнение имеет смысл реализовывать через 3-way сравнение. Так и поступите. Напишите функцию `compare_3way` для своего класса даты

```
template <typename T> inline int basic_compare_3way(T lhs, T rhs)
{
  return (lhs > rhs) - (lhs < rhs);
}

class Date 
{
  ...

  friend int compare_3way(const Date &lhs, const Date &rhs)
  {
    int cmp;

    if ((cmp = basic_compare_3way(lhs.m_year, rhs.m_year)) != 0 ||
        (cmp = basic_compare_3way(lhs.m_month, rhs.m_month)) != 0 ||
        (cmp = basic_compare_3way(lhs.m_day, rhs.m_day)) != 0)
      return cmp;

    return 0;
  }

  ...
```

И далее пользуйтесь именно этой функцией для реализации всех вариантов операторов сравнения

```
  friend bool operator <(const Date &lhs, const Date &rhs)
  {
    return compare_3way(lhs, rhs) < 0;
  }

  friend bool operator ==(const Date &lhs, const Date &rhs)
  {
    return compare_3way(lhs, rhs) == 0;
  }

  friend bool operator >=(const Date &lhs, const Date &rhs)
  {
    return compare_3way(lhs, rhs) >= 0;
  }

  ...
```

Полной инфраструктуры для поддержки этой идиомы в языке пока нет, но она появится в C++20. Имеет смысл ориентироваться на нее уже сейчас.

Comment: Тут еще следует выяснить стандартизировано ли преобразование логического типа к целому как подразумевается у вас, то есть `true == 1` а `false == 0`.